# Copy all Listbox items to a array

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell, listbox, copy

I have a listbox that contains PSObjects like this:

```
$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
  'Name' = 'SueAnne'
  'Region'= 'Northern'
}
```

The listbox looks like this (I set the `$listbox.DisplayMember = 'name'`):

```
|SueAnne  |
|Marge    |
|Rocky    |
```

*None of the listbox items are selected and I need to be able to copy the listbox items to an array.* This works if the listbox items were selected

```
$tempList = $listbox.SelectedItems
write-host $tempList[0..1]   #output just the first 2 items
```

> @{Name=SueAnne; Region=Northern} @{Name=Marge; Region=Southern}

But since they aren't selected is there a way to do this without looping through each item in the listbox?

Comment: `without looping` > No.

Comment: `This works if the listbox items were selected`  How many items are selected "when it works"?

Comment: So you want to get all of the listbox items regardless if they were selected or not? That sounds like what you are asking.

Comment: @Matt - I need all the items regardless of whether they were selected. @LarsTech - I'm saying that if you selected all three then `$tempList` would contain all three. I only output the first 2 in my example for simplicity.

Comment: What happens with `$listbox.Items`?

Comment: @Matt - Exactly what I need actually. Sorry, I was way over-complicating this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you are just looking for [ListBox.Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This property enables you to obtain a reference to the list of items that are currently stored in the ListBox.

So in your case the array you are looking for comes from `$listbox.Items`.